# Is the average multiplicative order of a finite field often small?

Tags: prime-numbers, finite-fields, average, upper-lower-bounds, multiplicative-order

It's possible to collect together all of the elements in a finite field of size $p$, $p$ prime, that have multiplicative order $\le \log{(p)}$, and put them in a set $s$.  My question is, how often is the size of this set, $|S| \ge \log{(p)}$?

I found [this PDF](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/ordertalk.pdf) that addresses the multiplicative order modulo $p$, on average, but I couldn't find out how to address my question from that paper.  The rest of the literature seems fairly scarce, so I'm hoping someone else can resolve this.

Comment: It's going to be based on the prime factorization of $p-1$. Not sure there is a reliable way to predict that.

Comment: @MorganRodgers:  I considered that maybe we may have to analyze a certain type of prime, or prime created from a certain type of function.  If we have some nontrivial lower bound, saying that it occurs at least as often as some bound, I believe I will accept that.

Comment: The number of elements in $\Bbb{F}_p^*$ of order $\le N$ is $\sum_{d\ |\ p-1, d\le N} \phi(d)$

Comment: @reuns:  I did think, when I first encountered the problem, that we could take primes that have a factor of $d!$.  Then we'd have primes $p = d! q+1$, and then we could almost guarantee a frequency of $\log{(p)} / d!$.  The problem with this is that $\log{(p)}$ grows somewhat as $p$ grows.  Plus, I need the $d!$ term to grow with $p$, also.